# Can I get the upper bound of the $L_2$ norm of a symmetric matrix?

Tags: matrices, normed-spaces

Suppose there is a symmetric matrix ${\textbf{A}}_{d\times d}$ with each element $a_{ij}$ draw from a Gaussian distribution $\mathcal{N}(0,\delta)$. Is there an upper bound of ${\left\| \textbf{A} \right\|}_2$? I know, for a symmetric matrix, the $L_2$-norm of it is the square root of its largest eigenvalue, but what is the largest eigenvalue of $\textbf{A}$? I would appreciate if someone could help me or give me some hints.

Comment: 2-norm is the largest singular value.

Comment: It seems to me that there cannot exist an upper bound simply because matrix A can be _any_ symmetric matrix... Besides, have you had a look at  random (or Wigner) matrices and Wishart distribution ? I have googled and found [this](https://math.berkeley.edu/~rezakhan/randommatrix.pdf) interesting article.

Comment: Indeed. There is not an upper bound for $L_2$ of $\textbf{A}$. How about the Expectation of it ($\mathbb{E}[{\left\| A \right\|}_2 ]$) ?